# Can you use super class methods as decorator methods - Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, inheritance, typescript-decorator

This is something that if I'm able to achieve will be able to design a very easily extendible decorator factory for a project I'm working on.

Basically, I want to be able to use a super class's methods as a decorator for the sub-classes property.

This is usually how decorators work:

```
import { handleSavePropertyNameDecorator } from "./W-ODecorator"

class Main {
    @handleSavePropertyNameDecorator
    test1: string = ""
}

export default Main
```

And then the decorator function:

```
const propertyNames = [];

export const handleSavePropertyNameDecorator = (_instance: any, propertyName: string) => {
    console.log("Executing handleSavePropertyNameDecorator")
    propertyNames.push(propertyName);
}
```

However, instead of defining a separate function for the decorator, I'd like the decorator function to come from the super class:

```
import SuperClass from "./SuperClass"

class Main extends SuperClass{
    @this.handleDecoratorFunction
    test1: string = ""
}

export default Main
```

```
class SuperClass {
    static propertyNameArray: string[] = [];

    protected handleDecoratorFunction(_instance: any, propertyName: string) {
        console.log("executing handle decorator function from super class!")
        SuperClass.propertyNameArray.push(propertyName);
    }
}
export default SuperClass;
```

Currently the keyword "this" has a compilation error that states it's possibly undefined. I've run this code and it doesn't execute the decorator function.

My question is this approach possible with some type of workaround? If this is possible that will significantly improve my organization.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't do that, the decorator is applied when the class is defined not when it's instantiated. There are no instance methods from your superclass available.

However, you can do this with a `static` method of course:

```
class SuperClass {
    static propertyNameArray: string[] = [];

    protected static handleDecoratorFunction(_instance: any, propertyName: string) {
        console.log("executing handle decorator function from super class!")
        this.propertyNameArray.push(propertyName);
    }
}

class Main extends SuperClass{
    @SuperClass.handleDecoratorFunction
    test1: string = ""
}

export default Main
```

Comment: Thank you for that confirmation! I was suspicious that that might be the case. And I have tried using static methods but I would need to be able to differentiate between the sub classes inside of the data.

Comment: Do you know if it’s possible to pass the name of the classs as a parameter to the decorator? From my experimentation it doesn’t appear possible

Comment: @ShawnWhitaker It [appears to be possible](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEDKCuAHApgJwMLitA3gKGkOkVQHsAXZYSgE2gnLHIEthoALMAOxpGQBEqpVE2EAxeF2rNSXABTMuDbsGQAuaNwCeAGmJkUqcloByYALbr65VIoDmASlwEir4LIik+AOhCk7cgAGyAAeVPAsXHbQNEIi5MLQAGaS0rLJZOb0SGjQoJAw6QAkOCSkhsZmlgC+0KRJ0CWKylLI3u5KNvDUwt5cFsjVAISBDi6E1XiTePnYALJgitChlDwwCIaYBfiuAAIbaFtQ3pw8fILu8eKpLLLj0JQMAIwaDLZR0AC80ABEP1NAA) with the usual `.constructor.name` (although I wouldn't use that to distinguish the subclasses - just use the class itself as a key in a `WeakMap`)

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I’m currently driving right now so I don’t have have the code with me. I do remember trying to do Class.constructor.name but I believe it gave me an error because the class hadn’t been defined yet. Once I get home I’ll verify if this is the case. And thanks for the suggestion using a weak map!